# What is the ideal ratio of front to rear wheel spoke count (disc brake)?

Tags: wheels, disc-brake, spokes

What is the best[1] ratio of front wheel spoke count to rear wheel spoke count on a disc brake bike?

For the vast majority of bicycles that are commercially available this ratio is 1: 32/32 for touring (Tout Terrain Silk Road, Koga World Traveller), 32/32 for MTB, 24/24 for road bikes (a particularly interesting case is the Giant TCR which moved from 21/24 (front/rear) in 2018 to 24/24 in 2023). But there is a tendency towards higher spoke count on the rear even though it's rare: Rolf (16/20) and AX lightness (20/24).

This question could be answered in several different ways that are all welcome: A) Anecdotal evidence. B) The most boring and simple answer would be to assume that the reason why most manufacturers have this ratio at 1 is that they have empirically tested different options and have all come to the same conclusion independently. On the other side they could have just copied each other and the solution might not be ideal and/or it's fashion to to a degree. C) An answer that is partially theoretical, partially empirical: something like this post https://www.cyclechat.net/threads/do-bikes-with-disc-brakes-break-more-spokes.226752/page-3#post-5045412 but going further and also taking the forces front and rear into account when hitting a pothole, when leaning into a turn (while breaking), when riding out of the saddle up a hill etc. This is an interesting intellectual exercise but it's difficult to take everything into account. D) This would be the gold standard answer: An empirical study comparing different spoke count configurations under controlled conditions with different load scenarios. I'm not aware of such a study or a study from which such conclusions could be drawn indirectly. Is anyone else?

If you think that there are differences between different bike categories you can assume the following bicycle: Road bike, weight of bicycle and rider = 100kg = 220 lbs, flat and mountainous terrain, mid deep (45mm) carbon rims front and rear. I do not think that these details matter but the more specific the question the better.

EDIT: [1] best = equal chance of breaking something on the rear and the front, equally adequate stiffness front and rear.

Comment: 36:36 is also common on tourers (as well as tandems, where you'll also see 36:40 and 40:40).  You'll also find 36:36 on cheap MTBs.  But these days a 1:1 ratio does seem to dominate

Comment: Yes that's my observation as well.

Comment: @ChrisH *But these days a 1:1 ratio does seem to dominate*  A front disk brake is going to put a lot of torque stress on the front wheel that a rim brake would not.  1:1 makes sense on disk-brake bicycles.

Comment: And this from your cyclechat link:  "I'm pretty confident that I can apply similar or greater torque to the rear hub by pedalling (sic) than the front disk brakes will generate"  Someone is delusional.  Can you pedal hard enough to "burn rubber" with your rear wheel?  Can you pedal hard enough to cause you to "reverse endo" or wheelie - **without** shifting your weight backwards?  The front brake is strong enough to either cause your front wheel to skid or have you endo over the bars, so it can put **more** torque on the wheel than your pedaling can.

Comment: Don't forget "aero"

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes indeed.  I've always thought extra spokes at the back are because of the extra weight on the back wheel, and not torque.  It's hard to compare the stresses from braking torque and the shock loads of hitting a pothole seated, but the front will definitely be experiencing more torque than with rim brakes

Comment: Everything is a trade-off. Ideal is ill defined without specifying what you consider the costs and what the benefits. In the end there'll be trade-offs between the two.

Comment: @user2705196 you are right. I will edit the post to specific what I mean by ideal.

Comment: Any idea why the question is down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote this but long walls of text with several suggested wrong answers in the question tend to annoy people.

Comment: Haha ok I see the point

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there is no "ideal" or "best" spoke count. Rather, it's a set of tradeoffs between weight, manufacturing costs, and strength. In general, the more spokes that a wheel has, the stronger it's going to be. (Lacing patterns, spoke thickness, and wheel size all play a part too, but we can ignore those for the sake of this discussion.) Adding those extra spokes increases the weight and manufacturing costs though.

Wheel strength is why you see a trend of more spokes on touring and mountain bikes than you do on road racers. The impacts of rough terrain or the extra weight of touring equipment simply requires stronger wheels. That's also why you see more spokes in the rear when the spoke count isn't 1:1. You have more weight on the rear wheel, so it needs to be stronger.

I'm not 100% sure about the 1:1 ratio being common, but I'd guess it has more to do with manufacturing costs and supply chain management than anything else. It's cheaper to manufacture and manage one rim type for any given bike than it is to manufacture and manage separate rims for the front and rear. 1:1 ratios were common before disc brakes, which indicates to me that disc brakes aren't the reason behind it.

As far as how manufacturer's arrived at the relatively standard numbers of 32 spokes for mountain bikes and tourers, and 24 spokes on road racers, it's probably more from market experience than anything else. There's been a lot of experimentation in the cycling market over the last 40-50 years. Manufacturers and consumers have both been willing to try a lot of different builds. Today's models are largely a reflection of what has been proven to work.

Comment: Thanks your reply, Jim. I have edited my post and defined what I mean by "ideal".

Comment: The update adds some clarity, but there still isn't, generally speaking, a "best" or "ideal." Too much depends on the rider's weight and style, as well as the terrain that they're riding on. In order to reach a reasonable definition, you'd need to specify a specific rider, riding a specific course, in specific conditions.

Comment: Thought I did that: "Road bike, weight of bicycle and rider = 100kg = 220 lbs, flat and mountainous terrain". Bike is ~10kg (it's a road bike) so rider weight is 90kg. Terrain is: mountainous and flat tarmac (because it's a road bike).

Comment: What's the rider's style? How hard do they bomb down hills? How much climbing is there? What are the corners like? How do they ride the brakes? Are there potholes? Slick spots? Thick seams in the concrete? The point is that from a manufacturer's perspective, optimizing a wheelset for any particular set of circumstances isn't practical. It's now suboptimal for all other purposes. "Ideal" or "best" has to be so narrowly defined as to no longer be useful, unless you have a garage full of wheels that you're willing to swap out for a given ride.

Comment: There can be a "best" for an average set of conditions which is what manufacturers have to do and what I had in mind.

Comment: *set of average conditions

Answer (score 3):

This is speculation based on listening to podcasts which interviewed cycling industry insiders. Industrial design is iterative, i.e. a manufacturer will produce a prototype, get feedback from experienced testers, then perhaps improve the prototype and finalize it. There might be several different prototype versions tested, there might be more than one round of testing. Then companies will begin again. Sometimes the process is slower, and there just isn't as much to iterate on.  I think bicycle hubs and spokes have seen less change over the last 20 years, although they definitely have seen improvements. For bicycle frames, one examplar I can think of is the Specialized Tarmac. The current version is the SL7, and an 8th version is rumored to be launching shortly. Aerodynamic carbon rims have seen a lot of iteration. I think aluminum rims saw less, although we did see some. This gets at what Jim was discussing about previous experience.

For example, in the days of box section wheels, I think the consensus might have been at least 32 spokes (with the materials science of the time). Racers might have gone down to 28 at times, but if you asked wheelbuilders, they would probably  not recommend that for many ordinary consumers. These days, manufacturers can add computerized tools like finite element analysis and other simulation models. The issue with those is that a designer needs to know what to put into the simulation, e.g. they may need a reasonably complete accounting of all the forces that act on a wheel as it is being pedaled on the road, including what impacts it might withstand. This is not a simple task.

In any case, my general recollection is that most aluminum performance rim brake wheels, as materials and rim design improved eventually converged on 20/24 spokes for most riders.  Carbon wheels always had fewer spokes due to the rims' stiffness, but I think they usually converged on the same spoke count. Some manufacturers push the limit or do things differently (e.g. some Hed wheels have 18/24 spokes, Campagnolo wheels have had 16/21 spokes, with the rear spokes going in a triplet arrangement; they weren't the first to ever do this, but the pioneers of this arrangement were small experimental wheelbuilders).

When road bikes started going disc, we had experience from the MTB side. It seems likely that they came to the same number of spokes front and rear based on the iterative processes discussed above. It's possible that the road industry simply extrapolated that experience - after all, we know that disc hubs see much higher forces than rim brake hubs, so a 20h disc front with otherwise might not be adequate for most riders, and it might be poorly received unless there was some demonstrable improvement in materials or engineering. Perhaps manufacturers confirmed it in testing, or from race experience and customer feedback. Once many people are doing one thing, it can be harder to convince people to do something different. Hence, I think we aren't likely to see disc wheels with fewer spokes on the front for a while, even if they are usable.

That's my guess at why current disc brake road wheels have converged on an even number of spokes front and rear, and they're often 24/24 spokes.

One minor issue is that the UCI have mandated that equipment manufacturers sell to the public anything that the pros are using. There aren't really ways around this for most manufacturers<sup>1</sup> - they can have the teams race on prototypes, but the equipment has to make its way to the public. In any case, even if (some or many) road racers were OK on 20/24 disc wheels, the manufacturer would have to sell that version publicly, which produces an additional set of SKUs. This might dissuade them from pushing the boundary there. Anyway, there are custom wheelbuilders, and they might be willing to experiment. One wheelbuilder said to me that he probably would not put even light riders on 20/24 spoke disc wheels, so there are probably limits to this.

---

Footnote 1: Adam Hansen, a very tech oriented weight weenie pro roadie, made his own ultralight custom carbon shoes while racing. [They are technically listed for sale](https://hanseeno.myshopify.com/collections/performance/products/u100g-shoes) to the public. They've always been listed as sold out ever since he had a storefront. They will say sold out when you click the link. I recall them being "sold out" years earlier. Trust me on this, but Hansen is a one-person shop and he can surely fly under the UCI's radar.

Or SRAM makes 54/41 chainrings available to pros due to drivetrain efficiency. These *can* be ordered by us plebeians, but they are only available in the power meter version, they cost a whopping amount (I believe they're listed as US$1,400+), and they are probably going to be special order only at most retailers - so you might be able to get a pair but the price and hassle should mean nobody is really going to buy them. You would be spending an *extra* $1,400 to effectively gain a 10s drivetrain, probably less than a watt at most speeds, and you also lose some low end gearing.

Comment: *I believe they're listed as US$1,400+* That's still pretty cheap compared to an SRM power meter.  But then again, my SRM is by far the best power meter I've used.

Comment: @AndrewHenle SRM was the pioneer, but the market evolved to put out PMs with comparable accuracy, much lower price, and don't SRM still want you to mail back the PM to get the battery changed? Anyway, this particular SRAM part is also a wear part.